# Load store into vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuex

while I am trying to load page it's showing me error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined". As per documentation I have tried this bus not loading store.

```
<template>    
<div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { store } from '@/components/tenant/store/store'
import Vue from 'vue'
export default {
store:store,
data: () => {
return {
}
}
}


store.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)

export const userStore = new Vuex.Store({
state: {}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I have misunderstood your question, but since you're exporting the const userStore, don't you need to do the following:

```
import { userStore } from '@/components/tenant/store/store';
```

Comment: Oho yes I have to use store instant of userStore thank you :)